# Clipboard Task error

Tags: c#

Here is the error I am getting:

> An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadStateException' occurred
>   in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Current thread must be set to single thread
>   apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your
>   Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it.

I am trying to assign a value to the clipboard within a `Task`. When I execute the code I get the error above.

Here is the clipboard code:

```
static public class ClipBoard
    {
        static private string _data = string.Empty;
        static public Semaphore ClipBoardSemaphore = new Semaphore(1, 1);

        static public void SetData(string data)
        {
            Clipboard.Clear();  //error here
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);
            _data = data;
        }

        static public string GetData()
        {
            return _data;
        }
    }
```

As you can see the error happens when the clipboard is cleared. 
Here is the code that invokes the Task:

```
for (int i = 0; i < zom.Count; i++)
{
     Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(zom[i].Process);
     t.Wait();
}
```

Comment: I am using console project

Comment: Right. So you'd be using the winforms libraries then? (System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard)

Comment: The answer is in the error message: *"Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it."*

Comment: Yes, it is markes on the main function but I still receive the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clipboard can only be accessed from an STA thread (typically the UI thread). So you'll need to invoke to the UI thread or another STA thread to do anything with the clipboard.